# Ajax URL generated by paginator/jquery helper encodes & as &amp;

Tags: ajax, cakephp, get, pagination, cakephp-2.1

Read bottom edit for workaround.

I'm having trouble implementing ajax pagination in my cakephp app.  I've looked for resources and tutorials to help with the issue however most deal with cake 1.3.  I've got my fingers crossed for a glaring and simple mistake on my part...

A description of where I'm at so far:  I have built a simple search interface for my application - a used car search interface that searches the cars in my database.  The search interface actually seems to be working fine.  I have a hidden form that creates or destroys hidden elements based on the users input in the search form.  This hidden form is submitted via Ajax successfully and I can return a set of paginated results such as "1-5 displayed of 16 found".

The problem I seem to be having is with the javascript enhanced number, next, and prev link/ajax requests that are being generated by the paginator helper.

My CarsController has the find_cars function that expects a get request (the $paginate var in my controller and the $this->Paginator options in the view both have dataType = querystring).   The function works fine on the initial form submission with a Get request url like: http://localhost/myapp/cars/findCars?price=any&year=any&miles=any

I have in my ajax.ctp layout $this->Js->writeBuffer(); and in the ajax response I can see the jquery events written for the next, number, and prev links.  An example of one event:

```
$("#link-1448104972").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({
dataType:"html", evalScripts:true, paramType:"querystring", 
success:function (data, textStatus) {
$("#results").html(data);}, url:"\/myapp\/cars\/findCars?price=any&amp;year=any&amp;miles=any&amp;page=2"});
```

The problem I'm having is with the URL value.  When I paste the url in a browser, my find_cars function processes the parameters correctly as the `&amp;'s`  get sent to the controller as plain &.  However when I click one of the pagination links that sends the ajax request,  the URL still contains the & encoded ampersands and $this->request->query; in a var_dump after a pagination click looks something like:

```
array
  'price' => string 'any' (length=3)
  'amp;year' => string 'any' (length=3)
  'amp;miles' => string 'any' (length=3)
  'amp;body' => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '6' (length=1)
  'amp;page' => string '2' (length=1)
```

The only other discussion I can find anywhere that seems to mention this same issue is in [this cakephp lighthouse bug ticket #127](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/127-query-string-escaped-in-ajaxjavacript-link-code) .  However the discussion is for cakephp 1.3 and the github commit it links to is a 404.

Edit:  I guess I should also add that I was trying to use GET requests so that I would have an easier time implementing expected user navigation & bookmarking capabilities to save search queries and navigate forward and backward through results with the browser as well as in app pagination links.

Edit (Workaround / Solution) - 
Working from @islandmyth's suggestion I switched over from doing a Get request to doing a Post, changed the paramType from 'querystring' to 'named'.  I pass the query info from $this->request->named to the view save the info to $this->Paginator->options['data'] having used php's http_build_query() function to preserve the nested arrays.

Comment: pagination link should look something like this http://localhost/cars/findCars/price:any/year:any/miles:any/page:2  and in the controller you can access the query string using $this->params['named']['year'] etc

Comment: @islandmyth  Would my pagination link look like this if I was using paramType:"named" rather than paramType:"querystring" In my paginate variable and paginator options ?

Comment: can you achieve that using the other approach?

Comment: @islandmyth  I made the changes to build the pagination link, something still goes wrong.   I'm passing the original query data from the controller to view and constructing a string to set as the URL for $this->Paginator->options['URL'].  I can get a URL that looks like http://localhost/karsquad/cars/findCars/price%3Aany%2Fyear%3Aany%2Fmiles%3Aany/page:2  This errors on submission with a response that "/karsquad/cars/findCars/price:any/year:any/miles:any/page:2" url wasn't found.  When I paste that link into a browser it returns the second page of results properly (in a blank ajax template).

Comment: Actually problem is with Js helper i.e with buffer function. In JavaScript, ajax URL contains that " amp; " . So WORK ROUND Solution is use string replace for your query string.

Answer (score 1):

Cake php Ajax Paginator not seems to be working fine. I had similar issues also.

I would recommend you to use the cakephp plugin [Cakephp-DataTable](https://github.com/tigrang/cakephp-datatable)

This plugin has implemented the pagination and it has most of the features by default. They have also provided documentation and if you find any difficulty in implementing please go throught the [issues section](https://github.com/tigrang/cakephp-datatable/issues/5#issuecomment-5229179)

Also the developer is very responsive and can get clarifications for that plugin if you have any.